# UIScrollView pinch zoom into CGContextStrokePath without changing line width

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d

I have a UIScrollView that contains a custom UIView. In my UIView I am overriding drawRect to draw a path using CGContextStrokePath. I would like to slightly alter the way the zoom works. Pinch zooming out will show more of the paths on the screen. This is what I want but i want the line width to stay the same not shrink as you zoom out so that they are still clear to the user.

I thought I would just do this (myUIView zoom target is called _lineView)

```
-(void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)pScrollView
    {
      _lineView.zoomScale = _scrollView.zoomScale;
      [_lineView setNeedsDisplay];
    }
```

and then just calculate an appropriate line stroke size in my _lineView drawRect method to give the effect of constant line width as you zoom out.

This is really slow and I have read that this is expected as drawrect is not optimised to be called many times a second.

I then started looking at using a GLKView instead and just rendering the whole thing in opengl directly. The problem with this is I will have to implement all of the zooming and panning myself (with all the lovely zoom and pan bounce effects you get for free in UiScrollView). I will also have to implement all the controls I want to use in opengl, buttons etc.

Is there a way to do this whilst still using Quartz2d? I feel like opengl will give me lots of power but it will take me much longer to get the rest of my app done if I go down that route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out. I found a simple way to do this that does not slow down the zoom / bouncing animations at all and is very fast and fluid.

Quartz has a class called CAShapeLayer that lets you do some pretty cool stuff. Among these is being able to set a CGPath property and specify a linewidth. Changes are reflected in the view.

So i basically call shapeLayer.lineWidth from my scrollViewDidZoom method and it does exactly what i need.

Comment: Thanks. I have follow this to drawing CGPath and zoom-out won't cause the line foggy. However, I have numbers of CGPath to be drawn with different color and lineWidth. Then I have to alloc each new CAShapeLayer for each CGPath and then add each layer as my view's layer subLayer. Would it cause some sort of performance issue if I add too much subLayer? Maybe I am over worried.

Comment: Yes eventually the drawing does slow down on older devices like iPhone 4 so be careful of that. It depends on how big the paths are though. If they only have a few line segments it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do if I were you is to use default zooming behavior while zooming (which does not redraw, but instead just applies a transform to the zoomed view, which can be done by the GPU very, very quickly, but as you have noticed can lead to inferior quality).

Then, when the user finished zooming, redraw the whole view as you do now. The appropriate delegate method is `scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:`.

This way, you have fast (but slightly ugly) zooming, and nice (but slightly, probably unnoticeably, slower) display after the zoom is finished.

Comment: hi fzwo i tried this option, and it does work but it still looks a little odd.

Comment: its not too bad if i change my line thickness calculation to something with a negative linear gradient like this (-_zoomScale * 10) + 20. Thats the fallback plan I guess which is fast but the line thickness changes are still noticeable.

Comment: There is no way around the line thickness changes being visible if you can't change line thickness in real-time due to performance constraints. If you want to be fancy, at the end of a scroll, fade between the old transformed and the new nicely rendered view to make the jump less obvious.

Comment: Even with this method it seems the zoom is not fluid, while you are pinching its fine but after you have released your fingers the draw call seems to cause the usual fluid bounce/elastic animation of the scrollview to jerk and stutter, not really ideal as it makes zooming look slow and jerky.